# Google Hangouts on Air button - how to get YouTube video ID programmatically

Tags: youtube, google-hangouts

I have a site where registered users can launch Hangouts on Air from a page. I need to be able to embed the video into the page for other users to view. However, the button API doesn't seem to callback with anything useful. Is there any way I can do this? I don't want to have to write my own Hangouts app because I can't have the viewers require a Google account to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering it late
You are on the right path,

To get the youtube id back in your application soon after the hangout is broadcasted, you have to :-

- Write a hangout app and load javascript in the .xml file
- In that script use [getYouTubeLiveId](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId) function to get the live youtube ID soon after the hangout is broadcasted
  thats it you are good to go..